# Get list of installed updates as part of Windows Updates using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, operating-system

I am very new to VBScript and I need to get the list of installed Softwares(For example Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 etc) as part of Windows Updates using VBScript or any.

If installed Softwares are listing under Add/Remove programs **using WMIC** we can get the list.

**wmic product where \"Name like**

But, for example Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 is installed as a part of Windows Updates which is not listing under Add/Remove programs.

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 is listed in the **Registries**. Here I need to get the list of such Softwares using VBScript or any.

I need this script for Windows 2008 R2 Standard Operating System.

Any kind of directions or solutions will be of immense help.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wmi registry class to enumerate keys in the registry.

---

EnumKey Method of the StdRegProv Class
The EnumKey method enumerates the subkeys for a path. See Obtaining Registry Data for general information on accessing the registry through WMI.

This topic uses Managed Object Format (MOF) syntax. For information about using this method, see Calling a Method.

```
uint32 EnumKey(
  uint32 hDefKey = 2147483650,
  string sSubKeyName,
  string sNames[]
);
```

Parameters
hDefKey 
[in, optional] A registry tree, also known as a hive, that contains the sSubKeyName path. The default value is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. 
Note that HKEY_DYN_DATA is a valid tree for Windows 95 and Windows 98 computers only.

The following trees are defined in Winreg.h.

```
Name Value 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT 2147483648
0x80000000 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER 2147483649
0x80000001 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 2147483650
0x80000002 
HKEY_USERS 2147483651
0x80000003 
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG 2147483653
0x80000005 
HKEY_DYN_DATA 2147483654
0x80000006
```

sSubKeyName 
[in] A path that contains the subkeys to be enumerated. 
sNames 
[out] An array of subkey strings. 
Return Value
In C++, the method returns a uint32 value that is 0 (zero) if successful. If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code that is defined in Winerror.h. In C++, you can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to get a generic description of the error. You can also look up return values under the WMI Error Constants.
In scripting or Visual Basic, the method returns an integer value that is 0 (zero) if successful. If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code that you can look up in WbemErrorEnum.

Example Code

For script code examples, see WMI Tasks: Registry and the TechNet ScriptCenter Script Repository. Other examples are in books and articles listed in Further Information.

For C++ code examples, see WMI C++ Application Examples.

The following VBScript example shows how to use the EnumKey method to enumerate the services listed as subkeys in the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

You can save the script as a file with a .vbs extension and send the output to a file by executing the command line in the folder that contains the script:
cscript Filename.vbs > output.txt

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"&_ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services"
objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys
WScript.Echo "Subkeys under " _
    & "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services"
For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
    WScript.Echo subkey
Next
```

---

This explains where it is stored.

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). Type for table format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:htable
```

or in a form format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:hform
```

It will create a html file on the desktop.

Note

This is not a full list. This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

or in a file

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUninstall.txt"
```

To see it in notepad in a different format

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type Regedit and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Right click the Uninstall key and choose Export. If you save as a reg file (there is also text file, they are slightly different text formats) you need to right click the file and choose Edit to view it.

To view Windows Updates

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUpdate.html" qfe  get /format:htable
```

### .