# Registry Query - Bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, findstr

I want to loop through all registry entries in a certain path and see if any of those match a string. I have the below bat file command:

```
reg query HKLM /f Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /v ProductName /s|findstr /r "abc - def (x64)"
```

I am using the `%errorlevel%` to determine the output of the above command. Expecting 0 when a registry exactly matching is found and non-zero when such a registry is not found.

However, I am getting 0 in both cases, i.e. a registry matches the string or it it doesn't.

Can you please suggest any correction to my bat command.

Comment: You are looking for abc OR a hyphen OR def OR x64? You know Reg can do it's own searching. See `/f` (and `/k` and `/d`).

Comment: Here's some details I posted - first half from Help, second half my stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079758/get-list-of-installed-updates-as-part-of-windows-updates-using-vbscript

Comment: @Noodles.. Thanks for reply. I am already using /f in Reg Query command. I am looking for a registry in which 'ProductName' matches the string "abc - def (x64)". I am looping through all the entries in the mentioned registry path, but findstr isn't matching the literal search string.

Comment: Are you escaping your brackets? \(x64\)

Comment: No, I am not escaping them. I am using just the same line as in the question

Comment: Do you read anything I say. *"You are looking for abc OR a hyphen OR def OR x64"*